# Is the usage of "I thank you" correct?

Tags: differences

Will it be okay if I write or say like this:

> I thank you.

When I saw someone write "I thank you", I said that usage is a bit awkward and rarely used.

I just want to know your opinion.

Comment: This reminds me of "Austin Powers", where he uses this phrase often after dishing out a pun! :)

Answer (score 5):

While we normally just say or write, "Thank you" (in which "I" is assumed), it is perfectly acceptable to say or write, "I thank you" instead. It adds a subtle emphasis and personalization to your response, although you are correct that it is *relatively uncommon* compared to the usual form. However, it is not considered rare or awkward usage.

Comment: Good answer. I would also suggest that the use of "I" makes the phrase a little more formal.

Answer (score 2):

"**Thank you**" is the popular usage.

You are correct in that "I thank you" is a bit awkward and rarely used.

In any case, "I thank you" is grammatically okay.